# how to install pandas for Python 3.x in windows 7 Platform..?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

how to install pandas for Python 3.x in windows 7 Platform..?

> I just downloaded the packages from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.18.1/#downloads

Comment: pandas has a lot of dependencies so it would be easier to install it with Anaconda. Check the [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#installing-pandas-with-anaconda) for details.

Comment: Continuum provides a great distribution for scientific Pyhton called Anaconda. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It contains the most used package and so pandas and its dependencies. They do a pretty good job, and the installation is easy on Windows -- this is not always easy to install numpy on Windows.